Unable to fetch search results from OpenLdap
I am trying to fetch all results from OpenLdap for the below search query, but I get zero results.
My java and Spring Boot code:
`LdapQuery query = query().base("cn=Devices,cn=DICOM Configuration,dc=dcm4che,dc=org")
.where("objectClass").is("\*");

List<String> results = ldapTemplate.search(query, (Attributes attrs) -> attrs.toString());
`

Below I have posted the screenshot of my OpenLdap structure:
OpenLdap Screenshot
I have tried many different combinations for fetching results, but none have returned any results.
Posted below are some of the queries that I have tried:
`.base("cn=Devices,cn=DICOM Configuration")
`

or
`.base("cn=Devices")
`

When I try the below query, it throws an error "No Such Object":
`.base("dc=dcm4che,dc=org") 
`

As per the screenshot "dc=dcm4che,dc=org" is the base, and the above query should work.
Someone please help.
